# Need if statement to run a task only if number of files in the directory are greater than 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I want to write a script, but I want an if statement so it will run only if the number of files in the directory are greater than 1. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Paste your current script in the question to solicit better answers!

Comment: The script is too large to fit in this box. I haven't tried anything yet since I don't have a clue how to do this.

Comment: @jlacroix82: You can paste the script in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and put the link here.

Comment: Here it is in Pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/4SGFHzVG

Please note that I am very sensitive about the script, I don't want anything changed other than the added functionality I'm requesting.

I put comments where I want it to check if there are more than one file before doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
[ "$(ls -b | wc -l)" -gt 1 ] && { ... your statements ... }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it with an if statement?

Comment: That is a (hidden/abbreviated) if..then statement. In full length, it would read `if [ "$(ls -b | wc -l)" -gt 1 ]; then ... your statements ...; fi`

Comment: The statements still run whether there is more than 1 file in the directory or not. Should I increase -gt 1  to -gt 2?

Comment: @jlacroix82: Don't forget this will also count directories, not only files. So if you have two directories inside the current directory the test will succeed even if there are no files.

Comment: There are no subdirectories at all, unless it's counting ..

Answer (score 0):

I will use something like:

```
    dir=.
    nf=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l`

    if [ "$nf" -gt "1" ] ; then
            <do something here>
    fi
```

This approach will only count `files` in the directory pointed by `dir` and discard any possible subdirectory.

Don't forget to change `dir` accordingly to your needs.

Comment: Just tried it, and the <do something here> will not run, even if there are files in the directory.

Comment: The [ test ]  statement may be incorrect: it uses strings (in quotes), but a numeric comparision (-gt). Try replacing that part by `[ $nf -gt 1 ]` (for a numeric comparision). If you want to do that with strings, it should be `[ "$nf" != "0" -a "$nf" != "1" ]`. Moreover you could (for test purposes) output the value stored in $nf before the line starting with "if".

Comment: @Izzy: That's wrong. The comparisson works with Strings.

Comment: @jlacroix82: Please. Make sure the current directory is what you want. Don't forget the `find` is finding files in the current directory. If you want you can change `find .` to `find <directory>`. Also you can put the command `pwd` in your script to know what is your current directory. The script was tested and it works.

Comment: @criziot: it may work (as sorted alphanumerically, any "string-number" larger than 1 starts with the digit 1 or up), but a) not good style and b) you never know about implementations whether "string -gt string" gets silently converted. The man page of `test` explicitly states: `INTEGER1 -gt INTEGER2: INTEGER1 is greater than INTEGER2`. Nothing about strings with "-gt". But don't we argue -- as long as it works ;)

Comment: @Izzy: Don't forget that `-gt` always perform arithmetic comparissons. If you try `"a" -gt "b"` it won't work. But I'm not an expert in bash to discuss this, I wrote it that way because it is how I'm used to see it (like [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)). And you're right, it is good as long as it works :D

Comment: @criziot: I'm also used to placing quotes around variables (to avoid trouble with blanks -- regarding those the quote marks are a very good thing), so I thought it was "accidentally". So nevermind, as we agreed: "as long as it works" ;)

Comment: @Izzy: There is no difference between `"11"`, `11` and even `"1"1` in shell. All are strings with two characters 1.

Comment: @jpalecek: Thanks, a test confirmed that `[ "11" -eq 11 ]`. So shell is basically "typeless" -- leaned something new :)

Comment: @jlacroix82: I just tried `if [ $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then echo 'Work to do!'; else echo "Go to bed."; fi` in a directory with 1 file ("Go to bed.") and with multiple files ("Work to do!") -- so it **does** work. This is basically the very same construct criziot offered, just "condensed".

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=($dir/*) # $dir was declared earlier if you look at my script
if (( "${#files[@]}" >= 2 ));
     <statements>
fi
shopt -u nullglob
```

The reason why none of the solutions posted here worked is because of the following. The script is executing the statements AGAINST the directories, it's not actually CD'ing IN to the directories. By telling it what folder I'm working with ($dir) it gets the hint and works as expected.

Comment: So the problem is basically what I've told you in my comment. Anyway I've edited my answer so you can see how to use a specific directory, but I'm glad you found a solution.